# How to create a function to show reviews in a view of my application (Swift-JSON)

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-places-api, swift4

I'm following https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details this doc to add all the information about a place, and for example to add "geometry"

```
 "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : -33.866651,
            "lng" : 151.195827
         },
```

i created this function in my class that work well

```
private let geometryKey = "geometry"
private let locationKey = "location"
private let latitudeKey = "lat"
private let longitudeKey = "lng"

class EClass: NSObject  {

 var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

init(placeInfo:[String: Any]) {

        placeId = placeInfo["place_id"] as! String


        // coordinates
        if let g = placeInfo[geometryKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let l = g[locationKey] as? [String:Double] {
                if let lat = l[latitudeKey], let lng = l[longitudeKey] {
                    location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

but but i'm having difficulty adding "reviews"

```
"reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
            "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
            "time" : 1491144016
         }
      ],
```

i tried to follow the same concept of the function i created for geometry like this

```
if let t = place.details?["reviews"] as? [String:Any] {
                   if let n = t["author_name"], let m = t["text"] {
                       Mylabel.text = "\(t)"
                   }
```

but is not working, i also tried to add a breakpoint and only the first line enters. What can i do? How can i create a build to show the review with a label or anything i need?

Comment: you are getting an array of dictonary in t , so use for each loop to iterate through this array. Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of `Codable` in Swift 4. You can simply convert your JSON into a specific struct. e.g. Based on your JSON:

```
let json = """
    {
        "reviews" : [
            {
                "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
                "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
                "language" : "en",
                "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
                "rating" : 5,
                "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
                "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
                "time" : 1491144016
            }
        ]
    }
    """
```

You can convert it into a `Response` struct using the following code:

```
struct Response: Codable {

    struct Review: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
        let text: String
        let authorName: String

        var description: String {
            return "Review text: \(text) authorName: \(authorName)"
        }

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case text
            case authorName = "author_name"
        }
    }

    let reviews: [Review]
}

do {
    if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let decoded = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
        print(decoded.reviews)
    } else {
        print("data is not available")
    }
} catch (let e) {
    print(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `t` is not a `Dictionary` it is an `Array` instead. So try doing something like this. Rest of that you can change as per your logic.

```
if let t = place.details?["reviews"] as? [String:Any] {
    for dic in t {
        if let n = dic["author_name"], let m = dic["text"] {
            Mylabel.text = "\(t)"
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, but You can also try to make it like that:

```
struct reviews: Codable{
    var reviews: [review]?
}
struct review: Codable{
    var author_name: String?
    var author_url: String?
    var language: String?
    var profile_photo_url: String?
    var rating: Int?
    var relative_time_description: String?
    var text: String?
    var time: Int?
}
```

And then:

```
if let dict = place.details?["reviews"] as? [String: Any], 
   let dataToDecode = dict.data(using: .utf8){
    do{
        let decodedReviews = try JSONDecoder().decode(reviews.self, from: dataToDecode)

     // here you have decoded reviews in array
    }catch let err{
        print(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: This code cannot work. In addition, classes should have an upper initial letter. e.g. `Review` instead of `review`